# Meteor: Exception in delivering result of invoking method

Tags: javascript, meteor

Similar issues have been posted, but none quite match what I've run into.  I'm doing a simple POST to an internal server to get back product data.  The call is successful and I see the JSON data correctly logging to my terminal when I do a console.log on the server side.  The issue arises on the client side, when in the callback, the result and error both are undefined.

Server:

```
Meteor.methods({
    ProductSearch: function(searchTerm) {
        var method = 'POST';
        var url = 'server';
        var options = {
            headers:{"content-type":"application/json"},
            data: { 
                query:"trees"
            }
        };
        return HTTP.call(method, url, options, function (error, result) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("ERROR: ", result.statusCode, result.content);
            } else {
                var txt = JSON.parse(result.content);
                console.log("SUCCESS: Found "+txt.totalResults+" products");
            } 
        });
    }
});
```

Client:

```
Meteor.call('ProductSearch', searchTerm, function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("error occured on receiving data on server. ", error );
    } else {
        var respJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
        Session.set("productSearchResults", respJson);
    }
});
```

When I log the values of *error*, and *result* on callback, they are both undefined, and I get the following error:  **Exception in delivering result of invoking 'ProductSearch': TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server-side method, you're not correctly returning the result of the `HTTP.call`, since you're using the asynchronous version, `HTTP.call` will return `undefined` and the result will only be accessible in the callback.

Use the synchronous version of `HTTP.call` instead and you'll be fine.

```
try{
  var result = HTTP.call(method, url, options);
  return JSON.parse(result.content);
}
catch(exception){
  console.log(exception);
}
```

See the corresponding docs for `HTTP.call` for additional information.

> **asyncCallback** Function
>
> Optional callback. If passed, the method runs
>   asynchronously, instead of synchronously, and calls asyncCallback. On
>   the client, this callback is required.

https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call

Comment: I cant tell you how many times I read the spec for `HTTP.call` and completely missed that the callback was optional!  Thanks a ton.